# How do you request request user permission for Windows Phone push notifications?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

The Windows Phone documentation states:

> The app must first describe the notifications to be provided and obtain the user’s express     permission (opt-in), and must provide a mechanism through which the user can opt out of receiving push notifications.

In iOS and Android it would appear that simply registering an app for notifications will prompt the OS to take care of prompting the user for permission and allowing the user to change this.

How do you do this in Windows Phone 8? Does the app have to:

- prompt for permission on first use
- provide a setting to opt out

Or is Windows Phone just like Android and iOS and the OS takes care of things for you?

Answer (score 1):

From the phrasing of `must provide a mechanism through which the user can opt out`, it seems there is no built in mechanism implemented by Windows Phone.

Therefore I assume that you should have some settings menu which specifies which push notifications your app wants to send and allows the user of the app to opt-out by un-checking the relevant check boxes.

That's not very different from Android. While newer versions of Android provide a settings option that disables all notifications for a specific app, individual apps might still want to supply an options menu that controls the frequency and type of notifications the user is willing to accept. BTW, in Android the only prompt the user gets about push notifications is in the list of permissions required by the app, so if they choose to install the app, push notifications are automatically enabled (assuming the app registers to GCM immediately), so it's not the same as the alert you get in iOS which asks you to allow push notifications.